# How to make owlcarousel more smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, owl-carousel

I am looking for an image slider which can be used by touch devices as well. I don't want to reinvent the weel and found the very nice jQuery Slider 
[owlcarousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/index.html).
[image]

On the page http://www.skyplugins.com/sky-jquery-touch-carousel/tooltip_skin_variation.html I found an other slider.
[image]
This slider slides more smooth without interrputions which looks much more better to me. I don't understand the technique behind this slider. Whats the difference to owlcarousel? Is it possible to merge the (much more) options from owlcarousel (example easy ajax image preloading) and make them more smooth scrolling like the other one? Does the other one only use an other css animation or is it somehow related to the jquery.touch library? I would like to understand the scrolling technique behind the second slider.

I hope you can help.

Regards Sturmi